# Проблемы с hover эффектом сдвигается изображение после модали

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ховер эффект работает нормально. При нажатии на кнопку Подробнее выскакивает попап как и положено. После закрытия попапа появляется вот такой эффект :

[1.Эффект после закрытия попапа][3]

Сдвигается изображение вверх.
После наведения мышки все стает на свои места.
Попап используется Bootstrap. Так же пробывал и magnificpopup, то же самое.
Использовал разные варианты с маржином, транслейт эффект тот же. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить.

```css
.activity-items {
   position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 45px;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 555px;
   height: 391px;
 }
.activity-items img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
}
.items-title {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 7;
top: 41.2%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
color: #fff;
font:30px/35px "RobotoMedium";
width: 56%;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
height: 72px;
}
.overlay-items .button-main-yellow {
 position: absolute;
 top: 61%;
 left: 28%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font:25px/25px "OpenSansRegular";
 padding: 10px 49px 14px 25px;
 text-transform: inherit;
 border: 2px solid #ef8e1c;
 background: #d77d14;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 5;
    }
.overlay-items .button-main-yellow i{
 margin-left: 15px;    }
.overlay-items {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
-o-transition: top 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1) 0s;
-moz-transition: top 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1) 0s;
-webkit-transition: top 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1) 0s;
-ms-transition: top 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1) 0s;
transition: top 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1) 0s;
z-index: 6;
}
.activity-items:hover .overlay-items{
  top:0;
   }




  
  [3]: http://prntscr.com/ejq7wu
```

```html
<div class="activity-items">
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg" alt="activity-img-1.jpg">
    <h4 class="items-title">Строительство элеваторов</h4>
    <div class="overlay-items">
     
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning button-main-yellow but-end-anim" data-mfp-src="#Modal-2" >Подробнее<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Для позиционирования кнопки в оверлее

Comment: Вот ссылка на сайт Блок Активность  [http://surokaztest1.zzz.com.ua/]

Comment: Извините. Исправил

Comment: Извиняюсь еще раз. Посмотрите пожалуйста сейчас. Все обновил